# How do I know when a DOM-element is created?

Tags: javascript, dom, onload, addeventlistener, qunit

I'm trying to acquire a reference for a specific QUnit DOM-element, as soon as this element is created. I can get it by using `window.setTimeout`, but is there an event-driven way to do it?

I have tried various approaches, but only the least satisfying (`window.setTimeout`) actually works:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var qunitTestrunnerToolbar_element = document.getElementById("qunit-testrunner-toolbar");
    console.log("from window.onload: qunitTestrunnerToolbar_element: ", qunitTestrunnerToolbar_element);
};
```

*returns null*

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
   var qunitTestrunnerToolbar_element = document.getElementById("qunit-testrunner-toolbar");
    console.log("from document.addEventListener(DOMContentLoaded): qunitTestrunnerToolbar_element: ", qunitTestrunnerToolbar_element);
});
```

*returns null*

```
document.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
    var qunitTestrunnerToolbar_element = document.getElementById("qunit-testrunner-toolbar");
    console.log("from document.addEventListener(load): qunitTestrunnerToolbar_element: ", qunitTestrunnerToolbar_element);
});
```

*is never executed*

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    var qunitTestrunnerToolbar_element = document.getElementById("qunit-testrunner-toolbar");
    console.log("from window.setTimeout: qunitTestrunnerToolbar_element: ", qunitTestrunnerToolbar_element);
}, 2000);
```

*returns the DOM-reference*

The code can be befiddled at [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/loldrup/ohaj23pz/).
Note that the fiddle only logs the one successful DOM-reference. The others are somehow silenced.

This is how it looks when executed locally:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the [`DOMMutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), which allows you to subscribe to changes to the DOM.

```
var mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
      mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        var id = 'qunit-testrunner-toolbar',
            added = mutation.addedNodes,
            removed = mutation.removedNodes,
            i, length;

        for (i = 0, length = added.length; i < length; ++i) {
          if (added[i].id === id) {
            //  qunit-testrunner-toolbar was added
          }
        }

        for (i = 0, length = removed.length; i < length; ++i) {
          if (removed[i].id === id) {
            //  qunit-testrunner-toolbar was removed
          }
        }
      });
    });

mutationObserver.observe(target, {childList: true});
```

If you need to stop listening for changes (as the amount of changes to the DOM can be huge ;) ), you can simply use `mutationObserver.disconnect()`.

If the `#qunit-testrunner-toolbar` is not the node that is added (but instead is part of another structure), the checks above will not work. If that is the case you can replace the `added[i].id === id` with something like

```
if (added[i].querySelector('#qunit-testrunner-toolbar')) {
  // it was added
}
```

---

I should at least mention the now deprecated [`Mutation Events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events), which seem more convenient to implement but were pretty slow and inaccurate.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
  if (e.target.id === 'qunit-testrunner-toolbar') {
  }
});
```

Tempting to use, but don't as it is deprecated.

Comment: From the documentation of DOMMutationObserver, it seems I need to supply a DOM reference as `target`. But this reference is the one I'm trying to acquire. It seems like a chicken-and-egg situation :/

Comment: You can provide the `document.body` as target, so you'll receive all changes within the body (this is _any_ change, not just changes to the body-elements children, so it includes (deep) descendants aswel).

Answer (score 0):

Everything you put in JSFiddle's javascript is already wrapped in onload event (so `window.onload` will never be fired again - it is already fired). Change it to "Javascript" -> "Load time" -> "No wrap - in <head>" and you will get all of your events fired.